# How to automatically store current system time on record generation in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I'm creating a database for an application. The table in question will be a log of all purchases made through the app, and one of the columns in the table will store the current date & time in DATETIME() (YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS format).

I know the SQL function Now() returns the current system date and time in this format, but can I create the table so that each new purchase automatically stores the current system time? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase_log (
//bunch of code
timestamp DATETIME() NOT NULL DEFAULT Now(),
//more code
);
```

So that by default each entry into purchase_log will automatically store the value returned by Now(), but I don't think this is valid SQL syntax. What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I don't think this is valid SQL syntax.

How? It's absolutely valid; Did you actually tried running that? If not then see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0b1a7/1

```
CREATE TABLE purchase_log (order_id int not null, 
order_name varchar(10),
orderdate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT Now()
);

insert into purchase_log(order_id, order_name) values(1,'laptop');
```

Comment: @jdogg, you most probably had the syntax error cause you were using `DATETIME()` instead of `DATETIME`. Here `DATETIME` is a datatype and not a function.

Comment: @Rahul *Hm...* I have a tendancy to leaning more towards not using ticks around the `timestamp` column being a reserved MySQL keyword. I could be wrong, but they're not in the OP's question, as originally posted. I'm not saying you're wrong though ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I really didn't got you are referring here.

Comment: @Rahul Look at the OP's post. There's no ticks `\`` around "timestamp" during table creation. Not having those, will throw a syntax error. However `DATETIME()` is also invalid. another syntax error.

Comment: Also I'd just like to add that this only works in mysql 5.6 and up. In older versions the type must be TIMESTAMP instead of DATETIME.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE  purchase_log (
`addedwhen` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

I used the fieldname "addedwhen" as "timestamp" is a MySQL reserved word.

- Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: good call on that. However, if OP is deadset on using `timestamp` at their column name, they can just use ticks `\`` around the column name during the table's creation and querying later on. Not suggested, but not impossible neither ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Add a default value to the field as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
However, while inserting data into the table, you will need to be careful.Either pass NULL to the field, or ensure proper timestamp.